# Creating many SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged events programatically

Tags: c#, windows-messages

sometimes my application freezes because the event `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` was triggered.
In order for me to better reproduce this error, I would like to send many of those events so I can increase the chance of my application freezing.

Is there any method that I can use (like `SendMessage` with a special Windows Message) to invoke this event programatically?
I have tried to use `SendMessage` with the windows message (`WM_WININICHANGE`) but the event handler was not called. I sent the message to the handle of my main window.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not your main window, it is a hidden window created by the SystemEvents class that processes the message.  Google "windows broadcast a message".  Usually pressing Win+L (lock workstation) is enough to trigger the deadlock.  Just aggressively pursue the 99.9% case of this bug, creating a form on a worker thread.